# Insert only figure number, without label, via cross reference in word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, cross-reference

I have figures with names such as "Figure A-1". I want to insert in the table of content the A-1 part, without the label Figure. In cross-references, there are options including the whole caption, and only `label and number`, but how do you only insert the number?

Answer (score 0):

On the left side of the Cross Reference dialog box, there are options. The one you want is labeled 'remove all non-delimiter characters' or something similar.
I'll post a pic shortly, I'm not at my computer.